# Typescript build "Cannot find module", but only on a ubuntu server

Tags: node.js, typescript, ubuntu, node-modules

I'm working on a node script and writing it in typescript. I've had no problems with running builds on my laptop (mac) or from my raspberry pi running raspbian.

I've gotten to the point where I want to set the codebase up on a digital ocean server that's running ubuntu. I moved the codebase up and ran my build script. The build completes successfully, but when I launch the node process I get the error:

```
node dist/server/source-server/index.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'express'
Require stack:
- /var/www/binary-operations-presentation/multi-player-server/dist/server/source-server/index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/binary-operations-presentation/multi-player-server/dist/server/source-server/index.js:6:35)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/var/www/binary-operations-presentation/multi-player-server/dist/server/source-server/index.js'
  ]
}
```

It's weird. I've run this codebase on multiple servers and none have had this issue. I did some searching around, but all of the answers I've found are saying "run npm install express" or "run npm install @types/express", both of which I have:

[image: dependencies]

Plus, if I didn't have them installed, the typescript compiler build would have failed.

I compared the file structure on the ubuntu server to my raspberry pi server and aside from the files that are generated when the codebase actually runs, the directories are the same:

[image]

Both servers have the same tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "../dist/server",
    "rootDirs": ["./", "../project-common/"],
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  }
}
```

And both have the same dependency versions:

```
// from package.json
{
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.0",
    "@types/ws": "^7.4.0",
    "killport": "^1.0.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "tsc-watch": "^4.2.9",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.11",
    "@types/lodash.clonedeep": "^4.5.6",
    "@types/websocket": "^1.0.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "lodash.clonedeep": "^4.5.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "ws": "^7.4.2"
  }
}
```

Neither of the `dist` folders have the node_modules folder, and when I look at the transpiled `index.js` file for the server they both import express the same way:

```
"use strict";
var __importDefault = (this && this.__importDefault) || function (mod) {
    return (mod && mod.__esModule) ? mod : { "default": mod };
};
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const express_1 = __importDefault(require("express"));
const http_1 = __importDefault(require("http"));
```

and both of the index.js.map files refer to the same relative source directory:

```
{"version":3,"file":"index.js","sourceRoot":"","sources":["../../../source-server/index.ts"]
```

So I'm not sure why one server would be able to refer back to the node_modules folder but the other one wouldn't.

The only big difference (aside from the OS version, the server is running Ubuntu 20.04) that I see is that my raspberry pi is running node 15.x and the ubuntu is running node 14.x, though I don't know that that would necessarily cause this problem.

Any ideas?

---

## UPDATE: same version of node

I tried making the version of node the same. I installed nvm on my raspberry pi, pulled in 14.6.0 (same version as the digital ocean server), rebuilt the project, and launched the server -> works fine.

[image]

so the node version doesn't seem to be a factor :/

Comment: What happens if you run it on node 14 on your pi? I personally use linuxbrew and nodenv to be able to have multiple versions of node that I can 'shim' at will so you can have lots of different ones available for testing. Maybe linuxbrew works on a pi?

Comment: @cefn same problem. I updated my question showing the details.

Comment: What's the mechanism for you installing express? Did you definitely run npm install from a clean checkout of the code (assuming it's in git). Sometimes switching architectures while keeping the directory contents doesn't work, since some parts of node are architecture-specific so they need to be installed actually on their target machine.

Comment: By the way you don't have to ever have @types as dependencies in a normal production system, only as devDependencies.

Comment: Oh, you don't need the @types for compilation? I didn't realize that. Good to know.

Comment: And yeah, I definitely npm installed. That said, I'm about to hop in the server to blow everything away and checking it out over again just to be sure. It's not live yet so it's no harm to fire that cannon

Comment: Just to be clear you ONLY need the types for compilation, so they are only needed at build time, and the expectation is that by the time code hits production it's already been built. There are exceptions to this but for most people (who are not actually doing weird engineering where the compiler is used at runtime) they don't need @types in dependencies, only in devDependencies.

Comment: It is really curious. Is it considered private code or can you open it to a github user @cefn for me to try and build/run it? I assume it follows a conventional npm build convention. Guess that would be discovered by looking at it for real. My guess is you're doing something differently than convention but maybe don't realise it. For example when you said e.g. moved the codebase up, it sounded like your workflow isn't to have a repo that can ALWAYS be checked out and built from nothing as part of conventional CI, so maybe there was ALWAYS something special about your machine that made it work.

Comment: Ah, yeah I'm def doing a bit of a hacky deploy b/c this is for a meetup talk demo, so building on the server was nbd, though if it's contributing to this issue I can def change it up. And yeah, it's a public codebase. The multiplayer server (what I'm trying to deploy now), is in a subfolder of the whole codebase: https://github.com/chris-schmitz/binary-operations-presentation/tree/main/multi-player-server

Comment: lots of repository cleanup to do, but you know, it is what it is :P

Comment: I added some quick up-and-running instructions to the readme.

Comment: Had a go https://github.com/chris-schmitz/binary-operations-presentation/issues/1 let me know what to try next - could dockerise and add rsync or try to workaround having no rsync

Comment: Setting it up in a dockerised environment now. There was a problem with artifactory npm targets in package-lock.json so I removed them with `find . -iname 'package-lock.json' -delete` and after that I could install. I wonder if your server-side install has been silently failing owing to the same problem and hence it didn't have express.

Comment: I can run gameboard, but the others have a permission denied error - probably because I'm running in a containerised environment (the inbound IP isn't localhost). However, I'm not experiencing issues from express or any other install failure since removing the package-lock.json files.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I'll try blowing away the lock file and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's the snag and solution:

The gist is that the compiled version of the index file is firing a regular node `require()` function to pull in modules:

[image]

Which means it goes through a number of steps to find the modules. [When it comes to possible node_modules modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders), it looks for the `node_modules` folder in the current directory. If node doesn't find it, node will step up to the parent directory and look there, continuing to step back to the root directory if node_modules directories aren't found.

In my case, I previously had all of the server and client code at the same directory level (the directory where the new subfolders now live). When I separated the code into the subfolders, I forgot to blow away the old node_modules folder locally, which is why the `dist` folder still found the `node_modules` folder that now resided at the parent directory of `dist`. When I did a `git pull` on my raspberry pi, the folders updated, but because `node_modules` is part of my `.gitignore`, that folder at the parent level wasn't blown away.

[image]

But, in newer clones of the repository of course wouldn't have node_modules at that parent directory, or any other parent directory so they bombed out.

While talking with @cefn I realized that I did want to have the `dist` be a "everything needed to run this project" directory, so I added a step to my npm `build` script:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "tsc --build tsconfig.json && npm run build:move-indexes && npm run build:move-node_modules",
    "build:move-indexes": "rsync -avz indexes ../dist/server/source-server",
    "build:move-node_modules": "rsync -avz node_modules ../dist/server/source-server",
```

This way, every time I rebuild the source code, the server will sync the `node_modules` in the `dist` directory with the `node_modules` in my source directory.

Tried it out, and it works :)